# How do I check whether the OnTriggerEnter function is called or not in an "if" condition in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a 3D-Bird game wherein which if it passes through a pipe( which has a box collider attached to it and its far end) a point is scored or else the point is not scored.

I am able to update the score if the bird scores a point. But if the bird doesn't score the point where it should score, I should be able to end the game.

For that in the Control script(which is attached to an empty object) I am keeping track of the Z position of the bird and the Z position of the pipe(Z is direction of forward movement of the bird).If the Z position of the bird is greater than the Z position of the pipe ,then the bird has passed the pipe. At the same time I want to check if the point is scored or not i.e.,the OnTriggerEnter function is called or not. How do I do this?

The partial code is below:

```
if (GameControl.instance.gameOver == false 
       && CurrentZpositionOfBird>CurrentZpositionOfScoringCollider 
       && ____________) {
```

In the above blank space I want to check if the OnTriggerEnter function is called or not

Comment: you can check when [OntriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) is called, in the Ontriggerenter itself. Set the method in your monobehaviour and the collider and component conditions that you can check in the docs for the method to be called when other trigger/collider enters

Comment: or introduce a bool variable called "isTriggerEntered", which you set it to TRUE in the OnTriggerEnter and use that variable in the statement above. Don't forget to set it to false afterwards. However, the better approach is what rustyBucketBay mentioned.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay could you elaborate more as to what you said?

Comment: @rootpanthera I kind of tried this .But you need to set it to false after 1 or two seconds of wait,which I am still working on

Comment: What @rustyBucketBay means is: Simply move your code to `private void OnTriggerEnter() { if (!GameControl.instance.gameOver && CurrentZpositionOfBird > CurrentZpositionOfScoringCollider) { ..... } }`

Answer (score 1):

`OntriggerEnter` is not a `bool` that you check, and if something has entered the trigger returns true (unless you code that yourself).

It is a "listener". It will be listening, so that when a trigger or collider enters in the one of your `Monobehaviour`'s conponent gameobject hierarchy where the `OntriggerEnter` is defined, will be executed.
Understand it as an event listener. The event it is lisnening to can be understood by the method name itself. As usually in programming with method names that are `OnWhatever()`

Documentation is very good. You need to check it.
Anyhow commented example below:

```
public class exampleScript : MonoBehaviour //This class is attached to a gameobj in the scene
{


    //This OnTriggerEnter method will be listening, so that when other 
    //trigger or collider  geometrically intersecs with yours,
    //the code inside this method will be executed. For this case just the 
    //log in the console, but can be whatever you might need to be done.

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Entered!");
    }
}
```